How to make Django-Q working for newest python/djang versions?
Django-q is only tested for up to python 3.9.  And indeed it is not working on python 3.10 and higher (at least for me). So knows anyone a way to use it for newer python and django versions?

just found django-q2,  seems to be the solution, anyone using already?  https://django-q2.readthedocs.io/en/master/#

django-q2 is a fork of django-q that works for Django >= 4.2, check it out here:
https://pypi.org/project/django-q2/
